# Android : throwing Paint IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

On some device my app is getting crashed , don't know why , I had integrated the bugsnag and captured the following stack trace , can you please tell what it's means:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException·
Raw
Paint.java:2762android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance 
TextLine.java:748android.text.TextLine.handleText   
TextLine.java:902android.text.TextLine.handleRun    
TextLine.java:417android.text.TextLine.measureRun   
TextLine.java:296android.text.TextLine.measure  
TextLine.java:270android.text.TextLine.metrics  
Layout.java:1056android.text.Layout.getLineExtent   
Layout.java:1012android.text.Layout.getLineMax  
Layout.java:984android.text.Layout.getLineRight 
Editor.java:1727android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAccelerated   
Editor.java:1663android.widget.Editor.onDraw    
TextView.java:6534android.widget.TextView.onDraw    
View.java:17469android.view.View.draw   
View.java:16464android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty   
View.java:17238android.view.View.draw   
ViewGroup.java:3921android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild 
ViewGroup.java:3711android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw  
View.java:16459android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty   
View.java:17238android.view.View.draw   
ViewGroup.java:3921android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild 
ViewGroup.java:3711android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw  
View.java:17472android.view.View.draw   
View.java:16464android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty   
View.java:17238android.view.View.draw   
ViewGroup.java:3921android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild 
ViewGroup.java:3711android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw  
View.java:17472android.view.View.draw   
View.java:16464android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty   
View.java:17238android.view.View.draw   
ViewGroup.java:3921android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild 
ViewGroup.java:3711android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw  
View.java:17472android.view.View.draw   
View.java:16464android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty   
View.java:17238android.view.View.draw   
ViewGroup.java:3921android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild 
ViewGroup.java:3711android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw  
View.java:16459android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty   
View.java:17238android.view.View.draw   
ViewGroup.java:3921android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild
```

Much More in same stacktrace:

```
CoordinatorLayout.java:1132android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild    
ViewGroup.java:3711android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw  
View.java:16459android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty   
View.java:17238android.view.View.draw   
ViewGroup.java:3921android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild 
DrawerLayout.java:1377android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild
```

Comment: Post logcat. This stack-trace Explains nothing

Comment: Your question title and your error **don't match**: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` is **not** an `Out Of Memory` error.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I can't see in the logcat because the app is checked by the client and we can trace it through bugsnag

Comment: @Rotwang is there any solution for this

Comment: See the duplicate post link

Comment: also add your code